# No tabview component in Form Builder

Tags: orbeon

I am looking for a tabview component in Orbeon Form Builder, but couldn't find it. Instead I found the link that unit test the tabview their  https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/tabview/tabview-unittest.xhtml

Is the tabview obsolete/deprecated or we may still use it through Form Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was never a general-purpose tabview component proper available in Form Builder. There is the [wizard view](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/feature/wizard-view.html) which might help you though.

The `fr:tabview` component is in fact obsolete even if you write XForms by hand. There is a new `fr:tabbable` component, which is currently reserved for internal use by the Form Builder UI.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.